# Equivalence of Brouwer's fixed point and corresponding retraction theorems with possible generalization

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

## **OVERVIEW**

This post is about section in Lawvere and Schanuel's book "Conceptual Mathematics" called **Brouwer's theorems**. More specifically, it is about clarification of description of an abstract category, in which retraction theorem is assumed and then fixed point theorem using the description (Axioms) of the category.

## **BACKGROUND**

Informally, Brouwer's fixed point theorems are theorems about continuous maps on a **Ball** $B \subset \mathbb R^n$. It states that, in category of continuous maps, $\forall f:B\rightarrow B, \exists b:1\rightarrow B \ s.t. \ f \circ b=b.$ Corresponding retraction theorems involve another object called **Sphere** $S$, which is the boundary of $B$. Suppose $j:S\rightarrow B$ is the inclusion map. Brouwer's retraction theorem says, $\nexists r: B\rightarrow S \ s.t. \ r\circ j=1_S$.

## **PROOF-SKETCH**

1) Construct a category $\mathscr C$, where all maps are continuous maps.

2) Introduce an object $A \in \mathscr C$ (Whose points are arrows in $B$) and specify its properties based upon idea that, one can draw a a ray from $b$ to $f(b)$, and extend it to intersect the boundary $S$ of $B$.

3) By assuming retraction theorem, show that fixed point theorem follows.

## **MY AXIOMS**

In category $\mathscr C$,

- All maps are continuous maps.
- Objects are some type of sets, where continuity of maps makes sense.

Note: Instead of inclusion map $j:S\rightarrow B$, I consider all monomorphisms $m:S\rightarrow B$, as I think, fixed point and corresponding retraction theorems will still be valid.

### **Axiom o**

Suppose $objects \ S, B \in \mathscr C, \forall m: S\rightarrow B, \exists A \in \mathscr C \ s.t. \ $ (A point of $A$ is called arrow in $B$)

- $\exists h:A\rightarrow B$, we say $h$ assigns a head to each arrow.
- $\exists \tau: A\rightarrow B \ s.t. \ \forall a:1\rightarrow A, \tau \circ a \ne h\circ a$. ($1$ is 1-set, and $a:1\rightarrow A$ is called point.)
- $\exists p: A\rightarrow S$. We say, $p$ assigns a point to each arrow to which the arrow points to.

### **Axiom 1**

$\forall \ object \ T \in \mathscr C, \forall a:T\rightarrow A, \forall s:T\rightarrow S, (h\circ a = m\circ s)\Rightarrow (p\circ a = s)$.

### **Axiom 2**

$\forall \ object \ T \in \mathscr C, \forall f,g:T\rightarrow B, \ either \ (\exists t:1\rightarrow T \ s.t. f\circ t = g\circ t) \ or \ (\exists \alpha : T\rightarrow A \ s.t. \ (\tau \circ \alpha = f \ and \ h\circ \alpha = g)$.

## **AUTHOR'S AXIOMS**

### **Axiom 0**

(There is no axiom 0, but object $A$ is introduced into $\mathscr C$ as following picture shows):

[image]

### **Axiom 1**

[image]

### **Axiom 2**

[image]

## **MY QUESTIONS**

### 1)

**Axiom 0**: Is my axiom 0 unnecessary? Why or why not?

### 2)

**Axiom 2**: Before stating axiom 2, author states that, an arrow must have a tail and head distinct, but he never actually formalizes the concept of arrow having a tail. Why? My confusion stems from following observations:

Suppose $f_1, f_2, g:T\rightarrow B \ s.t. \ (\exists t:1\rightarrow T \ s.t. \ f_1\circ t= g\circ t)\ and \ (\forall t:1\rightarrow T, \ f_2\circ t \ne g\circ t)$. Now, in former case, $\nexists \alpha:T\rightarrow A \ s.t. \ h\circ \alpha =g$. Then, in latter case, even though objects $T, A, B, g$ are all identical as in former case, but now $\exists \alpha:T\rightarrow A \ s.t. \ h\circ \alpha =g$. How is that possible? Why this $\alpha$ map was not possible in former case even though all objects in latter case were also in former case? There must be some additional property, that alpha must have, to explain this?

And, existence of tails explains this.

### 3)

Is my case for monomorphisms proven/disproven in any case? For example, in case, when one states Brouwer's retraction theorem for all monomorphisms from **Sphere** to **Ball** instead of the inclusion?

Thank you.