# There is no retraction map from unit disk to its boundary.(2)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory, retraction

There is no retraction map from unit disk to its boundary.

I was reading this proof:

> [image]

It is found here in this link [Retraction map from unit disk to its boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/213500/retraction-map-from-unit-disk-to-its-boundary)

But I do not understand why the map $i_{*}$ is an injection, could anyone explain this for me please?

Also if someone could write for me a more clear proof than this, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $r \circ i =1 \implies {(r \circ i)}_* = 1_* \implies r_* \circ i_* = 1 $ So $i_*$ has a left inverse! and thus is injective! (Since, for all $x,y$ , $i_* (x)= i_* (y) \implies r_* \circ i_* (x)= r_* \circ i_* (y) \implies x=y)$

Comment: so why the induced map is an injection? @Brozovic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis is that there is a section $i$ of $r$, that is, $r \circ i$ is the identity $1_{S^1}$ of $S^1$. Then it holds that $(r \circ i)_*=(1_{S^1})_*$. Moreover, the following two equalities hold:

$(1)$ $(r\circ i)_*=r_* \circ i_*$

$(2)$ $(1_{S^1})_*=1_{H_1(S^1)}$

Indeed, the functional relation sending a continuous map $f\colon S \to T$ to $f_* \colon H_1(S) \to H_1(T)$ is a *functor* and the request that $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold is precisely the definition of the notion of functor.

It follows that $r_* \circ i_*=1_{H_1(S^1)}$. Hence $i_*$ is injective.

Comment: so it is injective because it has a left inverse?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: What do you mean by there is a section i of r in your first line?

Comment: @Intuition, if in a category there are two arrows $A\xrightarrow{f}B$ and $B\xrightarrow{g}A$ such that $g\circ f=1_A$, then we say that $g$ is a _retraction_ of $f$ and that $f$ is a _section_ of $g$.